# What is the meaning of "cost-attractive"?

Tags: meaning

• Camping and caravanning are increasingly cost-attractive.

I don't understand what does 'cost-attractive' mean. What is the meaning of "cost-attractive"?

Comment: cost-attractive = attractive because of their (low) cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article ["Long-Haul Trips 'Cost-Attractive'"](http://www.easybus.com/en/blog/509-uk-travel-industry/1595-long-haul-trips-cost-attractive) from easyBus.com discusses the concept:

> Long-haul trips are proving attractive cost-wise, with Sri Lanka out on top as British holidaymakers struggle to cope with poor euro exchange rates, a survey said.
>
> Sri Lanka, which easily topped a holiday cost-of-living index of long-haul destinations, was 38% cheaper than nearest rival Thailand when it came to 10 categories including a meal out, drinks and sun cream.
>
> Vietnam, which welcomes more and more UK visitors each year, was the third least expensive country in the list.

So does the article ["KPMG Study: Nashville Among Most Cost-Attractive U.S. Cities for Businesses Sites"](https://www.bizjournals.com/nashville/blog/2014/04/kpmg-study-nashville-among-most-cost-attractive-u.html) from the Nashville Business journal:

> Business costs in Nashville are 5.1 percent below the national average, making it the second most cost-attractive mid-sized U.S. city for business relocations, according to a recent study by KPMG.
>
> Among cities and metropolitan areas with 1 million to 2 million residents, Nashville only ranked behind New Orleans.
>
> Hartley Powell, national leader for KPMG’s Global Location and Expansion Services practice, said Nashville’s strong labor pool, low labor costs and transportation network for companies to get their products to market contributed to its business attractiveness.
>
> “Anytime a company is looking at a location, generally the top two factors are the availability of labor and the quality of the labor,” Powell said. “Labor is always a huge driver, and Nashville was very strong in [availability] and low labor costs.”
>
> Along with workforce, Powell continued that being in close proximity to Memphis and its distribution hub makes Nashville “a home run” for attracting future businesses and corporations.

So, in whatever context, I take **cost attractiveness** to mean something that is appealing because of its low cost—but being inexpensive without sacrificing the quality or quantity of something that is being sought.

In specific relation to the question, I assume that camping and caravanning are cost-attractive because they allow people to go on vacation without spending very much money.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of the term before, but you can tell both from the individual words and the context what the term means: costing a relatively small amount of money. Since camping and caravanning cost a relatively small amount of money, these options are attractive ones; they are *cost attractive*.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, feel free to mark it as such. If it doesn't, good luck, and I hope you find a suitable answer.